# How to handle multiple request to limited number of items?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, scalability

I have a site that contains 100 available books.

But at the same moment of time I have 101 request that want to  reserve this book. How to handle this situation?

Comment: I think synchronization will be required while issuing (updating the book count) the books.

Answer (score 1):

[Robert Hanmer's book *Patterns for Fault Tolerant Software*](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118351541.html) has a pattern called **Queue for resources (46)**:

> **Store requests for service that cannot be handled immediately in a queue [...]. Give the queue a finite length to improve the likelihood that the request is still important when it reaches the head of the line.**
>
> When the requests are computer generated and must be processed in order, a First In First Out (FIFO) queue should be used. When people are generating the requests, the queue should use a Last in First Out (LIFO, a.k.a. a stack) strategy (as in FRESH WORK BEFORE STALE (55)) to govern insertion and removal. This will help people receive good service. The request that was placed on the queue last will think that they received excellent service, and the person that placed the longest ago request on the queue probably gave up already.
>
> Allocation of resources under the guidance of EQUITABLE RESOURCE ALLOCATION (45) should recognize both the requests that have been queued and those that are fresh and have never been queued.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a waitlist table which holds waitlisted/reserved requests with subscriber number, book id and time requested. Then when one of books is returned  - trigger a procedure which allots the freed book to the oldest waitlisted request and notifies the subscriber who has raised this request.

*Instead of a trigger* you can also have a scheduled jobs which runs daily/twice a day and checks whether any of the waitlisted books are available now. If available it allocates the book to the subscriber who has the oldest waitlisted request for that book.

Use trigger if your system load is not heavy, else use scheduled job and time it for non-peak hours.